# Get all strings/char starting with a symbol in Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have the below string -

```
" ?d a dm:Document .     ?d prism:doi ?doi . "
```

from this, I want a distinct list of words starting with '?' , including the '?'
How can I get it using scala string functions?

So what I want is:

```
?d ?doi
```

Although, there are 2 occurrences of "?d", I want only one (distinct)

Comment: This doesn't appear to be a Spark question. `"\\?\\w+".r.findAllIn(str).distinct.toList`

Comment: Thanks @jwvh, it works but its not supporting .distinct on the findAllIn(str).

Comment: for above one you have to change ```"\\?\\w+".r.findAllIn(str).distinct.toList``` to ```"\\?\\w+".r.findAllIn(str).toList.distinct``` It will work.

Comment: Both work with Scala 2.13.x.

Comment: oh okay @jwvh. 
My scala version is 2.11.8, may be thats why it didnt work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check below code.

```
scala> df.show(false)
+--------------------------------------------+
|value                                       |
+--------------------------------------------+
| ?d a dm:Document .     ?d prism:doi ?doi . |
+--------------------------------------------+

scala> val extract = udf((data:String) => "\\?\\w+".r.findAllIn(data).toSet.mkString(" "))

scala> df.withColumn("parsed",extract($"value")).show(false)
+--------------------------------------------+-------+
|value                                       |parsed |
+--------------------------------------------+-------+
| ?d a dm:Document .     ?d prism:doi ?doi . |?d ?doi|
+--------------------------------------------+-------+
```

**Scala**

```
scala> val data = " ?d a dm:Document .     ?d prism:doi ?doi . "
data: String = " ?d a dm:Document .     ?d prism:doi ?doi . "

scala> "\\?\\w+".r.findAllIn(data).toSet.mkString(" ")
res60: String = ?d ?doi
```

Comment: Thanks for the Answer, It worked, 
Lastly, if you can spend few mins and explain me, how this is working, it would be great.
"\\?\\w+".r.findAllIn(new_str).toSet.mkString(" ")

Comment: ```\\?\\w+``` this will find any words which start with ```?``` & then using toSet to remove duplicates & then creating string to get required output